# Is there a way to detect when the glasses are put downˆ

Tags: google-glass

Is there any means to detect when the glasses are put down?

Ideally, I'm looking for a broadcast event, but any other means will suffice. I must be able to differentiate when the glasses are actually put down versus going to sleep while still on the user's face.

App is native in Immersion mode.

Answer (score 0):

And here it is:

Broadcast action: ACTION_ON_HEAD_STATE_CHANGED

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/content/Intents